# Why doesn't this line draw at full length in `Graphics3D`?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to plot the real and imaginary parts of `Zeta[1/2 + t I]` with respect to `t` as a spiral line in 3D space. I want to draw in the critical line, and mark the points of intersection - i.e., the zeta zeroes. But my code does not draw the critical line at the full length of the plot.

The code is:

```
Module[{\[Sigma] = 0.5, minT = 10, maxT = 20, tStep = 0.01}, 
  zetaTable = 
    Table[{Re[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]], Im[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]], t}, {t, minT, maxT, tStep}];
  criticalLineTable = 
    Style[Line[{{0, 0, minT}, {0, 0, maxT}}], Darker[Green], Thick, Dashed];
  zetaZeroTable1 = Table[Im[ZetaZero[k]], {k, 1, 500}]; 
  zetaZeroTable2 = 
    DeleteCases[Table[If[zetaZeroTable1[[k]] > minT && zetaZeroTable1[[k]] < maxT,
    {0, 0, zetaZeroTable1[[k]]}], {k, 1, 500}], Null];

 Graphics3D[
  {{PointSize[Small], Darker[Blue], Point[zetaTable]}, 
    criticalLineTable,
   {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[zetaZeroTable2]}}, 
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {Style[TraditionalForm[Re[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]]], Large], 
    Style[TraditionalForm[Im[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]]], Large], 
    Style[TraditionalForm[t], Large]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  FaceGrids -> All]
 ]
```

which produces:

[image]

How do I make the green line cover the full interval `{{0, 0, minT}, {0, 0, maxT}}`? I suspect it may be something to do with the step size `tStep` - but all suggestions welcome.

Comment: No such problem in V12.2 (Mac).

Comment: Doesn't work in 12.1.0.0 (Mac)

Comment: Problem appears in 12.1 The culprit is "Dashed". Without it there is no problem. Seems a bug that has been fixed in 12.2 according to a previous note.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with `Dashing[]`. Maybe something like this instead: `criticalLineTable = With[{n = 50, d = 8},
   Style[
    Point[Table[{0, 0, t}, {t, Subdivide[minT, maxT, d*n]}], 
     VertexColors -> 
      Table[Opacity[Boole@Positive[Cos[Pi k/d]], Darker@Green], {k, 
        d*n + 1}]],
    PointSize[Small]
    ]
   ];`

Comment: Thank you all. It is indeed a problem with `Dashed` in MacOs 12.1. I shall endeavour to update. Given that @Daniel Huber provided the first answer, could you perhaps post is as an answer, and I'll tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of another (if clunky) way to approach the problem:

```
\[Sigma] = 0.5;
minT = 10;
maxT = 20;
tStep = 0.01;

zetaTable = 
  Table[{Re[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]], Im[Zeta[\[Sigma] + t*I]], t}, {t, 
    minT, maxT, tStep}];

greenLine = Table[{0, 0, i}, {i, minT, maxT, 0.1}];

ListPointPlot3D[
 {zetaTable, greenLine},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Darker[Green]},
 ImageSize -> 250,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {10, 20}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my mini answer:

Problem appears in 12.1 The culprit is "Dashed". Without it there is no problem. Seems a bug that has been fixed in 12.2 according to a previous note.